# What should be the input shape for convLSTM if ResNet-50 is applied before?

Tags: image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, feature-extraction, inceptionresnetv2

I have a video dataset, extracted all its frames, and applied ResNet-50 to extract features from all frames. **ResNet-50 provides feature map of (2534, 7, 7, 2048), 2534 are the number of frames.**
Now I have to apply convLSTM to train the model, but what should be its input shape.

Regards

Comment: What is the purpose of the model e.g. Classification/Regression etc?

Comment: classification model. To detect if a frame is anomolous or not.